# check for JRE on system

Tags: deployment, installation, java

I have an existing Java program that I am giving to some.... not so technically inclined clients of mine.  They use a combination of Linux, Windows, and very few have apple machines, which is why I chose Java to develop the program in.  The problem is they keep calling me with errors when they try to launch the program because they do not have a JRE installed.  Is there any way to:

1. Import a lib that will give me some kind of command to check.
2. Add something to the program that will check for the JRE.
   or (and I really don't want to go about this because of the reason I chose java in the first place)
3. Write something in C++ that will check for the JRE.

My aim:

1. Check if JRE installed on machine
2. If yes: Launch program
3. If no: pop up a message saying "No Java Environment found, downloading from Java website".  Then I would take them directly to the link where they hit "run" and it installs.

// i would do something like

```
if (JRE.exists()) // maybe use a pathname that would only show up if a JRE is installed
{
    // launch program
}
else
{
    // launch Java installer
}
system.exit(0);
```

I understand this would be really hard in java (as you cannot run Java programs without a JRE) but I prefer to keep this universal if at all possible.

If there is no easy fix, I'll just make a read-me file that has the link to the java website that checks for a JRE on your system, but the least amount of work the user has to do the better.

Comment: You cannot use Java for checking if Java exits. You need to do something before tying to lunch the Java program as creating batch.

Comment: Indeed, to run the code Java must exist already.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use an Java installer like IzPack or other such free tools. Using one of these you can create an installer and also generate a native launcher. This can be configured such as it searches for Java and if not found, it can help the user installing it.

There are developers that also use JSmooth or Launch4J for native launchers.

Comment: I looked into these, but they all require XML documents.  I do not have any XML experiance, any ideas where to start?

Comment: Any Java IDE will help you edit xml files. All these tools have examples and some have tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

> check for JRE on system

Use `deployJava.js` as mentioned in the [Java Web Start info.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) page.

> ..designed to ensure a suitable minimum version of Java is installed before providing a link to a JWS app. or launching an applet.

If it is a rich client desktop app. (e.g. applet or frame), deploy it using Java Web Start.

Comment: It's not an applet, it's just a standard Java Application

Comment: I never thought it was an applet.  But does the main class show a `JFrame`?  JWS was originally for launching frame based **desktop apps.**  As an aside, you can help us to help you by giving more details of the application.

Comment: I have a swing (JFrame) program that acts as a client that interacts with my server to store vectored data.  I have a message object that gets passed between the client and the server that allows clients to modify the vectored data.  I looked up the information on JWS and I like the concept, but still am not sure how to implement it.  I have a no-ip account that links an address to my IP.  This accomplishes everything I want (make sure Java is up to date and allows updates to the program) but I could use an example how to transform my code into a JWS app.

Comment: See the self-contained examples on [Java Web Start API demos](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html).  Note that those demos. use the API only available to JWS apps.  - which would require code changes.  But you can most likely get around code changes, so ignore the non-J2SE classes and look more at the JNLP files (describe the launch to the JRE, much like an `applet` element to configure an applet) and the file services demo. that shows how to digitally sign code (not sure if your app. needs trust).  No question was asked, so I infer the question as 'Way to achieve my aim?'.  That has been answered.

Comment: I have been doing more research.. I came across the IBM site about it and found a statement that said "Java Web Start must be installed on every machine that launches a client Java application from either the Web or from the Java Application Manager. Therefore, while a client Java application may be launched from a Web page, the application itself cannot be launched without first having Java Web Start installed on the local machine; thus the Web browser simply provides a convenient link for launching the program -- nothing more and nothing less." so this does not cure the no java problem

Comment: *"I came across the IBM site about it.."*  Given the IBM site is big, don't you think it might have been a good idea to provide a link?!?  In any case, it is likely pre-1.4.2 information.  Read the JWS info. pagae again, ***carefully*** where I summarize the history of JWS in relation to J2SE.  Note also that `deplpyJava.js` is designed to endure that a JRE is installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't go with Java Web Start, although I'd recommend using it, you can write simple scripts to detect Java.

**For Windows** (.bat):

```
if not "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" (
    "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe" -jar YourApp.jar
) else (
    start http://java.com/download/
)
```

If `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is defined, then `javaw.exe` will be started with your application jar file. The `javaw.exe` executable uses window subsystem thus it runs without console window.

If `JAVA_HOME` is not set, it will open the Java download page in the default browser.

For more options, you can use [JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72bd815a.aspx); with it you can display a warning to users that Java is not installed and then open the browser for download.

**For Linux** (.sh):

```
if [ "$JAVA_HOME" != "" ]; then
    $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar YourApp.jar &
else
    echo JAVA_HOME is not set: Java Runtime Environment (JRE)
    echo is not installed your system.
    echo Either install it from http://java.com/download/
    echo or set JAVA_HOME environment variable.
fi
```

Comment: The same script (.sh - bash) should work on MacOS. I've never worked with it, so I can't be really sure and I can't check it.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just create batch and bash files doing that and ask your customer to run  one or the other dependently on the OS

Comment: because i don't know bash :-(

Answer (score 0):

if the JRE is installed on a system, then JAVA_HOME environment variable is set on both Windows and Linux and it contains the path of JRE. You can check if this variable is set and accordingly proceed.

Comment: hmmm.... so i use if (!getenv("JAVA_HOME".equals(NULL))) {Launch program} else { // launch browser to install location}

Comment: granted i have to find the c++ equal to that and then that only suffices for windows and linux.  I would still have to find a way to do it for osX